# Why normal class methods can be used as slots in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

For given class definition:

```
class B : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   void normalFunction(){ qWarning() << "normal function";}
signals:
   void someSignal();
};
```

There is following code:

```
B a;
QObject::connect(&a, &B::someSignal, &a, &B::normalFunction);
a.someSignal();
```

The thing is that it is possible to use a normal method as a slot - no compilation errors, no runtime warnings, things seem to work ok. Is it correct behaviour to use normal methods (these ones which aren't declared in the `slots` section) as slots? I guess that metadata generated by moc is not used when connecting signals and slots using function pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is correct behaviour. Using the function pointer syntax you can connect to any member function, not only slots (see https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#New:_connecting_to_QObject_member below *pros*).

Answer (score 1):

> Why normal class methods can be used as slots in Qt?

Why not?

> I guess that metadata generated by moc is not used when connecting signals and slots using function pointers?

The metadata is used for the signal, but not used for the slot. The new connect syntax doesn't care what you connect to, but definitely does care for what you connect from. If the signal is not declared as such, the connection will fail at runtime even if it compiles successfully:

```
#include <QObject>
struct Test : public QObject {
  Q_SIGNAL void trueSignal();
  void fakeSignal() {}
  Q_OBJECT
};

int main() {
  Test test;
  auto c1 = QObject::connect(&test, &Test::trueSignal, []{}); // succeeds
  auto c2 = QObject::connect(&test, &Test::fakeSignal, []{}); // fails
  Q_ASSERT(c1);
  Q_ASSERT(!c2);
}
#include "main.moc"
```